# How to lock the azure sql database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am running an application that will connect an azure SQL database. I am running into a problem that the application will connect to the database in multiple threads, thus causing race conditions. I want to run them sequentially.

I can't change the application, is there a way to set the database to allow a single connection only, if it doesn't then wait until it connects?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot make Azure SQL to limit to just single connection. For on prem SQL versions, you can put a database in a `single user` mode - so that only one user can connect to it, but that is not what you want.

Comment: Based on your used database you could try to limit the max concurrent connections to a very low value. Which DB offering exactly are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Single user mode is not available on Azure SQL Database.

However, maybe you should consider adding a retry logic on the application so it can retry X times and the interval between retries can be increased after a retry fails.

```
public void HandleTransients()
{
    var connStr = "some database";
    var _policy = RetryPolicy.Create < SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy(
        retryCount: 3,
        retryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    using (var conn = new ReliableSqlConnection(connStr, _policy))
    {
        // Do SQL stuff here.
    }
}
```